# Spool Space Error. Please help optimize

Tags: teradata, spool

I am trying to generate the below query in Teradata SQL Assistant.  Unfortunately I am running into a spool space error.  Any tips on how to make this query execute using less resources?

```
SELECT TOP 10
        A.USER_ID, 
        C.SUPER_NM_LVL2,
        C.SUPER_NM_LVL1, 
        DIR.SUPER_NM_LVL2,
        A.ACTIVITY_DT,
        B.MTN, 
        A.ACCT_NUM,
        A.PPLAN_CD_CURR

FROM DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V AS A

INNER JOIN 
            CUST_ACCT_LINE_V AS B
            ON A.ACCT_NUM=B.ACCT_NUM

INNER JOIN 
            HR_EMPLOYEE_V AS C   
            ON A.USER_ID=C.NT_USER_ID 

INNER JOIN 
            HR_EMPLOYEE_V AS DIR
            ON C.SUPER_ID_LVL2_EMP_ID=DIR.EMP_ID

WHERE 
            A.ACTIVITY_DT >= '2012-11-01' 
            AND A.ACTIVITY_DT <= '2012-11-19'
            AND C.EMP_AREA_CD = 'WE'
            AND A.PPLAN_CD_CURR IN ('86489', '86491', '86492', 
                '86494', '86495', '86496', '86497', '86498', '86499', '86500', '86501', 
                '86502', '86487', '86489', '86504', '86505', '86506', '86507', '86508', 
            '86509', '86510', '86511', '86512')

GROUP BY 
        A.USER_ID, 
        C.SUPER_NM_LVL2,
        C.SUPER_NM_LVL1, 
        DIR.SUPER_NM_LVL2,
        A.ACTIVITY_DT,
        B.MTN, 
        A.ACCT_NUM,
        A.PPLAN_CD_CURR
```

EDIT: Here is the explain statement.

```
Explanation
  1) First, we lock UDM_PRDSTG_SECTBLS.MASKING_PROD_NM_XREF in view
     NTL_PRD_ALLVM.CUST_ACCT_LINE_V for access, we lock
     UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
     NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V for access, we lock
     UDM_PRD_TBLS.CUST_ACCT_LINE in view NTL_PRD_ALLVM.CUST_ACCT_LINE_V
     for access, and we lock UDM_PRD_TBLS.HR_EMPLOYEE in view
     NTL_PRD_ALLVM.HR_EMPLOYEE_V for access. 
  2) Next, we execute the following steps in parallel. 
       1) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from a single partition of
          UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V with a condition of (
          "(NOT (UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.ACCT_NUM IS NULL ))
          AND ((NOT (UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.USER_ID IS NULL ))
          AND ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.ACTIVITY_DT <= DATE
          '2012-11-19') AND ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in
          view NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.ACTIVITY_DT >=
          DATE '2012-11-01') AND ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN
          in view NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR
          = '86489') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86487') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86491') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86492') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86494') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86495') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86496') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86497') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86498') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86499') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86500') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86501') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86502') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86504') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86505') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86506') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86507') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86508') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86509') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86510') OR ((UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86511') OR (UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V.PPLAN_CD_CURR =
          '86512')))))))))))))))))))))))))") into Spool 9 (all_amps)
          (compressed columns allowed), which is built locally on the
          AMPs.  The size of Spool 9 is estimated with low confidence
          to be 2,908,683 rows (119,256,003 bytes).  The estimated time
          for this step is 0.02 seconds. 
       2) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from UDM_PRD_TBLS.HR_EMPLOYEE
          in view NTL_PRD_ALLVM.HR_EMPLOYEE_V by way of an all-rows
          scan with a condition of ("(NOT (UDM_PRD_TBLS.HR_EMPLOYEE in
          view NTL_PRD_ALLVM.HR_EMPLOYEE_V.NT_USER_ID IS NULL )) AND
          ((NOT (UDM_PRD_TBLS.HR_EMPLOYEE in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.HR_EMPLOYEE_V.SUPER_ID_LVL2_EMP_ID IS NULL ))
          AND (UDM_PRD_TBLS.HR_EMPLOYEE in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.HR_EMPLOYEE_V.EMP_AREA_CD = 'WE'))") into Spool
          10 (all_amps) (compressed columns allowed), which is
          duplicated on all AMPs.  The size of Spool 10 is estimated
          with low confidence to be 31,938,444 rows (2,012,121,972
          bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.67 seconds. 
       3) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from UDM_PRD_TBLS.A in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.CUST_ACCT_LINE_V by way of an all-rows scan
          with a condition of ("(( CASE WHEN (NOT (UDM_PRD_TBLS.A in
          view NTL_PRD_ALLVM.CUST_ACCT_LINE_V.CUST_ASSOC_ID IS NULL ))
          THEN (UDM_PRD_TBLS.A in view
          NTL_PRD_ALLVM.CUST_ACCT_LINE_V.CUST_ASSOC_ID) ELSE (' ') END
          ))<> '12'") into Spool 11 (all_amps) (compressed columns
          allowed) fanned out into 14 hash join partitions, which is
          built locally on the AMPs.  The size of Spool 11 is estimated
          with no confidence to be 186,602,214 rows (5,784,668,634
          bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 2.27 seconds. 
  3) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 9 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan, which is joined to Spool 10 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan.  Spool 9 and Spool 10 are joined using a single
     partition hash join, with a join condition of ("USER_ID =
     NT_USER_ID").  The result goes into Spool 12 (all_amps)
     (compressed columns allowed), which is duplicated on all AMPs into
     14 hash join partitions.  The size of Spool 12 is estimated with
     low confidence to be 360,568,332 rows (30,648,308,220 bytes).  The
     estimated time for this step is 8.09 seconds. 
  4) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 11 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan, which is joined to Spool 12 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan.  Spool 11 and Spool 12 are joined using a hash join
     of 14 partitions, with a join condition of ("ACCT_NUM = ACCT_NUM"). 
     The result goes into Spool 13 (all_amps) (compressed columns
     allowed), which is redistributed by the hash code of (
     UDM_PRD_TBLS.HR_EMPLOYEE.SUPER_ID_LVL2_EMP_ID) to all AMPs.  The
     size of Spool 13 is estimated with no confidence to be 8,247,457
     rows (783,508,415 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is
     1.01 seconds. 
  5) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from UDM_PRD_TBLS.HR_EMPLOYEE in view
     NTL_PRD_ALLVM.HR_EMPLOYEE_V by way of an all-rows scan with no
     residual conditions, which is joined to Spool 13 (Last Use) by way
     of an all-rows scan.  UDM_PRD_TBLS.HR_EMPLOYEE and Spool 13 are
     joined using a single partition hash join, with a join condition
     of ("SUPER_ID_LVL2_EMP_ID = UDM_PRD_TBLS.HR_EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID"). 
     The result goes into Spool 8 (all_amps) (compressed columns
     allowed), which is built locally on the AMPs.  The size of Spool 8
     is estimated with no confidence to be 8,247,457 rows (882,477,899
     bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.06 seconds. 
  6) We do an all-AMPs SUM step to aggregate from Spool 8 (Last Use) by
     way of an all-rows scan , grouping by field1 (
     UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN.USER_ID
     ,UDM_PRD_TBLS.HR_EMPLOYEE.SUPER_NM_LVL2
     ,UDM_PRD_TBLS.HR_EMPLOYEE.SUPER_NM_LVL1
     ,UDM_PRD_TBLS.HR_EMPLOYEE.SUPER_NM_LVL2
     ,UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN.ACTIVITY_DT
     ,UDM_PRD_TBLS.A.MTN ,UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN.ACCT_NUM
     ,UDM_PRD_TBLS.DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN.PPLAN_CD_CURR).  Aggregate
     Intermediate Results are computed globally, then placed in Spool
     14.  The size of Spool 14 is estimated with no confidence to be
     8,247,455 rows (2,762,897,425 bytes).  The estimated time for this
     step is 0.76 seconds. 
  7) We do an all-AMPs STAT FUNCTION step from Spool 14 by way of an
     all-rows scan into Spool 18, which is redistributed by hash code
     to all AMPs.  The result rows are put into Spool 5 (all_amps),
     which is built locally on the AMPs.  This step is used to retrieve
     the TOP 10 rows.  Load distribution optimization is used.
     If this step retrieves less than 10 rows, then execute step 8. 
     The size is estimated with no confidence to be 10 rows (1,130
     bytes). 
  8) We do an all-AMPs STAT FUNCTION step from Spool 14 (Last Use) by
     way of an all-rows scan into Spool 18 (Last Use), which is
     redistributed by hash code to all AMPs.  The result rows are put
     into Spool 5 (all_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs.  This
     step is used to retrieve the TOP 10 rows.  The size is estimated
     with no confidence to be 10 rows (1,130 bytes). 
  9) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.
  -> The contents of Spool 5 are sent back to the user as the result of
     statement 1.
```

Comment: have you tried tools/explain (F6) ?  In general, you can query the largest table first in a subquery, then join all the little ones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Beth.  I'm aware of the feature, just not sure how to apply it.  Self taught here, but I'll post the explain results in my OP.

Comment: How many rows in each of the tables?  I'm assuming one or more are huge (millions) and others, medium-sized (thousands).  Cut down your huge tables first, then join to medium-sized tables.

Comment: These are huge tables that hold information on transactions for millions of customers and thousands of employees' information.  When you say cut down on the tables, what are you referring to?  Sorry if this is obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try moving your limiting criteria closer to your massive tables:

```
SELECT TOP 10
        A.USER_ID, 
        C.SUPER_NM_LVL2,
        C.SUPER_NM_LVL1, 
        DIR.SUPER_NM_LVL2,
        A.ACTIVITY_DT,
        B.MTN, 
        A.ACCT_NUM,
        A.PPLAN_CD_CURR

FROM 
    ( SELECT * FROM DLY_LINE_ACTIVITY_PPLAN_V
    WHERE
        ACTIVITY_DT >= '2012-11-01' 
        AND ACTIVITY_DT <= '2012-11-19'
        AND PPLAN_CD_CURR IN ('86489', '86491', '86492', 
            '86494', '86495', '86496', '86497', '86498', '86499', '86500', '86501', 
            '86502', '86487', '86489', '86504', '86505', '86506', '86507', '86508', 
            '86509', '86510', '86511', '86512')
    )
    AS A

INNER JOIN 
            CUST_ACCT_LINE_V AS B
            ON A.ACCT_NUM=B.ACCT_NUM

INNER JOIN             
    (SELECT * FROM  HR_EMPLOYEE_V
    WHERE
    C.EMP_AREA_CD = 'WE' ) C   
    ON A.USER_ID=C.NT_USER_ID 

INNER JOIN 
            HR_EMPLOYEE_V AS DIR
            ON C.SUPER_ID_LVL2_EMP_ID=DIR.EMP_ID

GROUP BY 
        A.USER_ID, 
        C.SUPER_NM_LVL2,
        C.SUPER_NM_LVL1, 
        DIR.SUPER_NM_LVL2,
        A.ACTIVITY_DT,
        B.MTN, 
        A.ACCT_NUM,
        A.PPLAN_CD_CURR
```

Comment: This looks good, except that I would just `SELECT ACCT_NUM, USER_ID, ACTIVITY_DT` in the first derived table (rather than `SELECT *`). And I'd also first try adding `AND C.EMP_AREA_CD='WE'` to the `ON` clause rather than create a derived table.

Comment: Yes, you're more familiar with what you need from each table than I am.  Does it work?

Comment: Not my question, just pitching in.

Comment: Thanks so much for the input, both of you!  This definitely has me thinking outside of the box.  I'm going to continue playing with the derived tables, unfortunately I'm still getting a spool space error. :(  Thank you so much for the ideas, however!

Comment: ciw916, try executing it in pieces.  First, just execute A.  does that have a problem?  I'm guessing it doesn't, and it's some other addition that's causing the problem.

Comment: Ended up taking the format from your answer and adding ONE join condition to the CUST_ACCT_LINE_V table (most likely the largest of all the tables being referenced).  I am now pulling back info.  Thank you so much, Beth!  Enjoy the rep points.  haha